# Erro ao realizar a autenticação Basic Auth em API REST no android

Tags: java, android, api, spring-boot, spring-security

Estou com muita dificuldade em realizar a integração com uma API utilizando a autenticação basic auth.

Criei uma API em Java utilizando spring boot e spring security.

Quando utilizo o Postman a requisição funciona sem nenhum problema, porém quando tento realizar a requisição via o codigo do APP recebo um codigo negado 401.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
String stringUrl = strings[0];
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
        StringBuffer buffer = null;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conexao = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conexao.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", authHeader);
            conexao.setConnectTimeout(20000);
            conexao.setReadTimeout(20000);
            conexao.setDoOutput(true);
            conexao.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conexao.setRequestProperty("grant_type", "password");
            conexao.setRequestProperty("username", "edimilson");
            conexao.setRequestProperty("password", "123");
            conexao.setRequestProperty("scope", "read,write");
            conexao.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
           // conexao.connect();

            int responseCode = conexao.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == 200){
                // Recupera os dados em Bytes
                inputStream = conexao.getInputStream();

                //inputStreamReader lê os dados em Bytes e decodifica para caracteres
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader( inputStream );

                //Objeto utilizado para leitura dos caracteres do InpuStreamReader
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( inputStreamReader );
                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String linha = "";

                while((linha = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    buffer.append( linha );
                }
            }else {
               // exibirMensagem("Houve um problema no envio da mensagem: " + responseCode);
                return "Houve um problema no envio da mensagem. \n" +
                        " " + responseCode;
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return buffer.toString();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

tenta assim nessa linha:

```
conexao.setRequestProperty("scope", "read%20write");
```

Comment: Encontrei o problema. 
Simplesmente a minha URL não estava recebendo os parametros. 
http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?...
Após concertar esse problema funcionou normalmente